# Python groupby delete row with condition

Tags: python, dataset, conditional-statements, rows

I'm new on python and I have an issue.

My original dataset is like this one: 
[Original dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cxXN.png)

and I would like to get: [final dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqOsa.png)

So the idea is to delete:

- single demand, and
- rows where there is only one different id_user per demand.

I manage to delete single demand with a Counter() but I'm stuck there:
[probleme here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOozJ.png)

I don't want to do it manually with index because my proper dataset has more than 30000lines.

Can someone help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

Load your dataset in to a dataframe:

I'll create your dataframe here:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'demand':[1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7,7,7,7,8,8],'id_user':[101,102,101,101,101,101,103,102,101,101,104,104,104,105,105],'invoice':[10,10,10,60,-60,60,10,10,10,20,20,-20,30,10,10]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    demand  id_user  invoice
0        1      101       10
1        1      102       10
2        2      101       10
3        3      101       60
4        3      101      -60
5        3      101       60
6        4      103       10
7        5      102       10
8        6      101       10
9        7      101       20
10       7      104       20
11       7      104      -20
12       7      104       30
13       8      105       10
14       8      105       10
```

Let's use `duplicated` and boolean indexing:

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=['demand','id_user'],keep=False)]
```

OR

Let's use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby(['demand','id_user']).filter(lambda x: x.demand.size != 1)
```

Output dataframe:

```
    demand  id_user  invoice
3        3      101       60
4        3      101      -60
5        3      101       60
10       7      104       20
11       7      104      -20
12       7      104       30
13       8      105       10
14       8      105       10
```